# How to swap deployment slots for web apps with virtual applications

Tags: azure, web-applications

I have an existing web app with one virtual application.
Later I added a deployment slot for staging.
The deployment slot was created cloning the main web app.
When I swapped the production slot for the staging slot the virtual application was gone.
Am I missing a checkbox or setting?
Is there a solution or workaround for that?
Well, apart from creating separate web apps for each virtual application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Applications/Directories are swapped along with the web site content of a slot. This behaviour is not configurable at this time.

E.g.

> - A web app Production slot has an additional Virtual Application configured on it an a second slot Staging does not.
> - After a swap, Production slot will only have the default Virtual Application (/) and the Staging slot will have the additional Virtual Application.

From your question, it sounds like you have done a swap with both slots containing an additional Virtual Application and have ended up with only the default Virtual Application.

I tried the swap multiple times and the additional Virtual Application swapped each time. So my suggestions, are:

- to double check that the Virtual Application is not in other non-Production slot
- check that you are setting a physical path to something beginning with "site\wwwroot"

Hope that helps.